# Chapter menu like Apple one

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, menu

I want to recreate with pure HTML, CSS and Javascript the experience of the upper part menu of this apple page: https://www.apple.com/services/
I want to recreate the selection fo Apple One, Apple TV+ and so on.

I recreate in HTML and CSS (also copy from the Apple website) the structure and I create this pen:

```css
.chapternav{
  background:#333;
}
.chapternav-paddle {
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 1.7647058824;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    font-family: SF Pro Text,SF Pro Icons,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    border: 0 solid #d2d2d7;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #1d1d1f;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33px;
    transition: opacity 150ms ease-out
}
.chapternav-paddle:after {
    opacity: .8;
    transition: opacity 200ms linear
}

.chapternav-paddle:disabled {
    opacity: 0
}

.chapternav-paddle:hover:after {
    opacity: 1
}

.chapternav-paddle:focus {
    outline: none
}

.chapternav-paddle:focus:after {
    outline: 4px solid rgba(0,125,250,.6);
    outline-offset: 4px;
    opacity: 1
}

.chapternav-paddle:active,.chapternav-paddle:focus:after[data-focus-method=mouse]:not(input):not(textarea):not(select),.chapternav-paddle:focus:after[data-focus-method=touch]:not(input):not(textarea):not(select) {
    outline: none
}

.chapternav-paddle:active:after {
    outline: none;
    opacity: 1
}


.chapternav-paddle-left {
    border-right-width: 1px;
    left: 0
}

.chapternav-paddle-left:after,.chapternav-paddle-left:before {
    font-family: SF Pro Icons;
    color: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: 1;
    text-decoration: underline;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    alt: "";
    text-decoration: none
}

.chapternav-paddle-left:before {
    display: none
}

.chapternav-paddle-left:after,.chapternav-paddle-left:before {
    content: "<"
}

.chapternav-paddle-left:after {
    margin-left: -0.5px
}

@supports(left: calc(max(0px))) {
    .chapternav-paddle-left {
        left:calc(max(env(safe-area-inset-left) + -10px, 0px))
    }
}

.chapternav-paddle-right {
    border-left-width: 1px;
    right: 0
}

.chapternav-paddle-right:after,.chapternav-paddle-right:before {
    font-family: SF Pro Icons;
    color: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: 1;
    text-decoration: underline;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    alt: "";
    text-decoration: none
}

.chapternav-paddle-right:before {
    display: none
}

.chapternav-paddle-right:after,.chapternav-paddle-right:before {
    content: ">"
}

.chapternav-paddle-right:after {
    margin-right: -0.5px
}

@supports(right: calc(max(0px))) {
    .chapternav-paddle-right {
        right:calc(max(env(safe-area-inset-left) + -10px, 0px))
    }
}


.ac-nav-overlap .chapternav,.chapternav-overlap .chapternav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}

.ac-nav-overlap .chapternav {
    margin-top: 44px
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .ac-nav-overlap .chapternav {
        margin-top:48px
    }
}

.chapternav.theme-dark,.theme-dark .chapternav {
    background: rgba(29,29,31,.7)
}

@supports((-webkit-backdrop-filter: initial) or (backdrop-filter:initial)) {
    .chapternav.theme-dark,.theme-dark .chapternav {
        background:rgba(29,29,31,.6)
    }
}

.chapternav-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1
}

.chapternav-tall {
    height: 116px
}

.chapternav-items {
    margin: 0 34px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding-bottom: 50px
}

@supports(margin: calc(max(0px))) {
    .chapternav-items {
        margin:0 calc(max(env(safe-area-inset-left) + 24px, 34px))
    }
}

@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    .chapternav-items {
        padding-bottom:49px
    }
}
.chapternav{
    padding: 8px 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 9987;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden
}
.chapternav-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1
}
.chapternav-items {
    margin: 0 34px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding-bottom: 50px
}
.chapternav-item {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0 -0.1176470588em;
    padding: 0 20px
}
.chapternav-item:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 4px
}
.chapternav-item:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-right: 4px
}
.chapternav-icon {
    background: bottom no-repeat;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 7px;
    height: 54px
}
.chapternav-label {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.3333733333;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: -0.01em;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
}
.chapternav-link {
    color: #1d1d1f;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 3px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1
}
.chapternav-link:hover {
    color: #06c;
    text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<section id="test-menu">
    <nav id="chapternav_1" class="chapternav">
        <div class="chaptervav-wrapper">
            <ul class="chapternav-items">
                <li class="chapternav-item chaptervan-item-1">
                    <a href="" class="chapternav-link">
                       <figure class="chapternav-icon" style="background-size: 56px 54px;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-image: url('https://www.apple.com/v/services/h/images/services/chapternav/dark/apple_one_dark__eu2pb1ea55g2_large.svg');width: 56px">
                        </figure>
                        <span class="chapternav-label">Apple&nbsp;One</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="chapternav-item chaptervan-item-1">
                    <a href="" class="chapternav-link">
                       <figure class="chapternav-icon" style="background-size: 56px 54px;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-image: url('https://www.apple.com/v/services/h/images/services/chapternav/dark/apple_one_dark__eu2pb1ea55g2_large.svg');width: 56px">
                        </figure>
                        <span class="chapternav-label">Apple&nbsp;Two</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="chapternav-item chaptervan-item-1">
                    <a href="" class="chapternav-link">
                       <figure class="chapternav-icon" style="background-size: 56px 54px;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-image: url('https://www.apple.com/v/services/h/images/services/chapternav/dark/apple_one_dark__eu2pb1ea55g2_large.svg');width: 56px">
                        </figure>
                        <span class="chapternav-label">Apple&nbsp;Three</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="chapternav-item chaptervan-item-1">
                    <a href="" class="chapternav-link">
                       <figure class="chapternav-icon" style="background-size: 56px 54px;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-image: url('https://www.apple.com/v/services/h/images/services/chapternav/dark/apple_one_dark__eu2pb1ea55g2_large.svg');width: 56px">
                        </figure>
                        <span class="chapternav-label">Apple&nbsp;Four</span>
                    </a>
                </li>                                                
            </ul>
            <div class="chapternav-paddles">
                <button class="chapternav-paddle chapternav-paddle-left" aria-hidden="true" disabled></button>
                <button class="chapternav-paddle chapternav-paddle-right" aria-hidden="true" diabled ></button>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </nav>
</section>
```

https://codepen.io/clickpiu/pen/wvQoogz

The problem is when it goes on mobile view. Apple, when the list overflow from the view put a beautiful arrow on the right and on the left... and if the user click it scroll viewing the others element. Someone can help me to recreate this effect?
Thanks

Comment: The main effect is called a [carousel](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=css+carousel). There are many variations but this will help narrow your search.